# How can I get the "lea" instruction from a C++ function by disassembly?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn reverse engineering, and I'm stuck on this little thing. I have code like this:

```
.text:10003478                 mov     eax, HWHandle
.text:1000347D                 lea     ecx, [eax+1829B8h] <------
.text:10003483                 mov     dword_1000FA64, ecx
.text:10003489                 lea     esi, [eax+166A98h]<------
.text:1000348F                 lea     edx, [eax+11FE320h]
.text:10003495                 mov     dword_1000FCA0, esi
```

and I'm wondering, how does it look like in C or C++? Especially the two instructions marked by arrows. `HWHandle` is variable which holds the a value returned from the `GetModuleHandle()` function.
More interesting is that a couple of lines below this instructions, `dword_1000FCA0` is used as a function:

```
.text:1000353C                 mov     eax, dword_1000FCA0
.text:10003541                 mov     ecx, [eax+0A0h]
.text:10003547                 push    offset asc_1000C9E4 ; "\r\n========================\r\n"
.text:1000354C                 call    ecx
```

This will draw this text in my game console. Have you got any ideas, guys?

Comment: I'd advise you to disable code optimization on the compiler, since it could produce a machine code sometimes hard to understand, with lots of simplifications / re-writtings / re-organizing.

Comment: OTOH with disabled optimizations the compiler introduces seemingly needless loads and stores to the same addresses, which can make the disassembly hard to read, as the few relevant lines in which actually something is happening are so few in between. I prefer `-O1`.

Comment: What game console are you working on? Xbox?

Comment: No no, i ment console like command prompt :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `HWHandle` is a module handle, which is just the base address of a DLL, it looks as if the constants that are being added to this are offsets for functions or static data inside the DLL. The code is computing the addresses of these functions or data items and storing them for later use.

Since this is typically the job of a dynamic linker, I'm not sure that this assembly code corresponds to actual C++ code. It would be helpful to know what environment you're working in exactly -- since you refer to games consoles, is this Xbox code? Unfortunately, I don't know how exactly dynamic linking works on Xbox, but it looks as if this may be what is going on here.

In the specific case of `dword_1000FCA0`, it looks as if this is the location of a jump table (i.e. essentially a list of function pointers) inside the DLL. Your second code snippet is getting a function pointer from offset 0xA inside this table, then calling it -- apparently, the function being called outputs strings to the screen. (The pointer to the string to be output is pushed to the stack, which a usual x86 calling convention.) The C++ code corresponding to this would be something like

```
my_print_function("\r\n========================\r\n");
```

Edit:

If you want to call functions in a DLL yourself, the canonical way of getting at the function pointer is to use `GetProcAddress()`:

```
FARPROC func=GetProcAddress(HWHandle, "MyFunction");
```

However, the code you posted is calculating offsets itself, and if you really want to do the same, you could use something like this:

```
DWORD func=(DWORD)HWHandle + myOffset;
```

`myOffset` is the offset you want to use -- of course, you'd need to have some way of determining this offset, and this can change every time the DLL is recompiled, so it's not a technique I would recommend -- but it is, after all, what you were asking but.

Regardless of which of these two ways you use to get at the address of the function, you need to call it. To do this, you need to declare a function pointer -- and to do that, you need to know the signature of your function (its parameters and return types). For example:

```
typedef void (*print_func_type)(const char *);
print_func_type my_func_pointer=(print_func_type)func;
my_func_pointer("\r\n========================\r\n");
```

Beware -- if you get the address of the function or its signature wrong, your code will likely crash. All part of the fun of this kind of low-level work.

Comment: Yes, your first paragraph is exactly what i needed to hear and that's true! I exactly have to use function concluded in this DLL, but now is the question - how can i do that?

EDIT

That's my idea: By adding offset to HWModule address i can gain address to function icnluded in this DLL, right? And i can do it that way:
http://wklej.org/id/699418/

Then in my func variable i will have an address to func. How i will be able to call out that function with parameter like that string?

Comment: About that GetProcAddress() - i know it's better but i don't know what is function name, but i'm sure that it won't be recompiled. Okey, i wrote it and i've got something like that : http://wklej.org/id/699603/   Should be fine?

Comment: @Blood: That sort of depends on what you're doing. You can use the dumpbin utility (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429/en-us) with the /exports switch to get a list of all the functions exported from the DLL -- then you'll know the name to use with `GetProcAddress()`. If the function you're after is an internal function, this won't work -- in this case you're on pretty shaky ground anyway, but you probably know that...

Answer (score 5):

**LEA is nothing more than an arithmetic operation** : in that case, ECX is just filled with EAX+offset (the very address, not the pointed contents). if HWHandle pointed to a (very large) structure, ECX would just be one of its members.

This could be an associated source code:

```
extern A* HWHandle;                 // mov     eax, HWHandle
B* ECX = HWHandle->someStructure;   // lea     ecx, [eax+1829B8h]
```

and later, one of B’s members is used as a function.

```
*(ECX->ptrFunction(someArg))        // mov     ecx, [eax+0A0h]
                                    // call    ecx
```

Comment: Actually, we know what kind of "structure" `HWHandle` points to -- it's a module handle, i.e. the base address of a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `HWHandle` is apointer to some structure (a big one). `lea` instruction is reading address(es) from that structure, e.g:

```
mov eax, HWHandle
lea ecx, [eax+1829B8h]
mov dword_1000FA64, ecx
```

means:

1. Read address from `HWHandle + 0x1829B8` and put it into `ecx`
2. Put that address (from `ecx`) into some (global) variable `dword_1000FA64`

The rest looks simmilar.

In C++ you can get it almost anywhere and you really cannot predict where (depends on a compiler and optimizations), e.g.:

```
int x;
int* pX = &X;
```

The second line may generate `lea`.

Another example:

```
struct s
{
   int x;
   int y;
};
my_s s;
int Y = s.y; //here: probably lea <something> , [address(my_s) + 0x4]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ this is roughly equivalent to

```
char* ecx, eax, esi;
ecx = eax+0x1829B8   // lea ecx, [eax+1829B8h]
esi = eax+0x166A98   // lea esi, [eax+166A98h]
```

Under the assumption that eax, esi and ecx are really holding pointers to memory locations. Of course the lea instruction can be used to to simple arithmetic too, and in fact it often is used for addition by the compilers. The advantage compared to a simple `add`: It can have up to three input operands and a different destination.

Answer (score 1):

For example, `foo = &bar->baz` is the same as (simplified) `foo = (char *)bar + offsetof(typeof(*bar), baz)`, which can be translated to `lea foo, [bar+offsetofbaz]`.

Answer (score 0):

It really is compiler and optimization dependent, but if IIRC, `lea` could be emitted just for additions.... So `lea     ecx, [eax+1829B8h]` can be understood as `ecx = eax + 0x1829B8`